# How to show properties of listbox selected item in different controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

In my application I have a window which contain a `ListBox`, and controls that should show different properties of its currently selected item. Those controls are:

1. `TextBox` that should show 'Name' property.
2. `TextBox` that should show 'DataFile` property.
3. `DataGrid` that should show 'TItems property, which is an `ObservableCollection`.

I tried to bind `SelectedItem` to an object, and then bind different properties of that object to the controls mentioned above, with no success.

The window:

[image]

My View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReportMaker"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ReportMaker.ViewModel" x:Class="ReportMaker.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Create" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,36.667" Width="119" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="134,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" DataContext="{Binding SelectedReportItem}">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 10, 0, 0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Data File:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding TItems}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,92,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ReportItem> ReportItems { get; set; }
    public object SelectedReportItem { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ReportItems = new ObservableCollection<ReportItem>();
        ReportItems.Add(Example);
    }
    public ReportItem Example = new TextReportItem() { Name = "John", DataFile = "try.txt"};
}
```

ReportItem:

```
public class ReportItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataFile { get; set; }
}
```

TextReportItem:

```
public class TextReportItem : ReportItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextParcel> TItems { get; set; }
}
public class TextParcel
{
    char Delimiter { get; set; }
    string LineExp { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
    string IgnoreLine { get; set; }
    int DesiredResultIndexInLine { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** as I use MVVM, I prefer to use only XAML in the View, with no code behind.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to S.Akbari I succeeded to view the desired properties in the `TextBox` controls, with the following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Data File:"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.DataFile}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

But when the same logic is applied to my `DataGrid`, it fails for some reason:

```
<DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.TItmes}" />
```

I also tried:

```
<DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding TItems}"/>
```

And also:

```
<DataGrid Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TItems}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You need `Binding.ElementName` Property and `Path` for this purpose like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129379/set-visibility-of-button-depending-from-selected-tab

Comment: I already tried to bind to `ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem`, but what I really need is a single property of that `SelectedItem` for each control. Is there a way to bind to a property of the selected item?

Comment: Well your path should be like this: `Path=SelectedItem.propertyName`. for example: `Path=SelectedItem.DataFile` or `Path=SelectedItem.Name`.

Comment: Thank you, this works for Name and DataFile in the Textboxes, but not for TItems in the DataGrid. What am I missing here?

Comment: I will. Do you know why the data binding doesn't work for the DataGrid?

Comment: for `DataGrid` you should use `ItemsSource` and then have a template inside the `DataGrid` that shows selected items elements.

Comment: Could you demonstrate with a code snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106142/discussion-between-aviran-katz-and-s-akbari).

Answer (score 1):

if you use MVVM your view model should raise property changed events

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
and change the selected item to be a full property
see :[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx)