# Combobox selected item binding to GridViewColumn and GridViewColumn binding to combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to have my selected combobox value = to the textbox value.  I want this to be in xaml only if possible.

```
<ListView x:Name="ExampleLV" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Example1Collection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Values[0].Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<ComboBox Name="ExampleCB" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Example2Collection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, 
          Path=SelectedItem.Values[0].Value, Mode=TwoWay, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
             <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, Path=SelectedItem.Tag, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem isn't that the selected List item isnt updating, rather the combobox selected updating isn't updating to match the listview selected item.

And Yes, the Values[0].Value has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Here is a similar post, see what you missed over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129379/set-visibility-of-button-depending-from-selected-tab

Comment: My combobox is using those attributes already.

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood whether you need binding to listview(Question subject) or to Textbox(Question body). Here is pure XAML solution for both of them:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"


    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="ExampleLV" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=Cbox, Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>Test1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Test2</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Test3</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Column1"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Cbox, Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>

        <ComboBox x:Name="Cbox">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>Test1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Test2</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Test3</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>                
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your answer, supplies no answer.  I dont need textbox binding, i need Gridviewcolumn.Displaymemberbinding
Evenything in your answer i already cover, your not supply a solution just re printing my code in your own way.

Comment: As I have pointed in my answer - the question is not clear enough. Provide more information about viewmodel and what you are after.