# How i can change button's IsEnabled property from DataTrigger on ListBox style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

How can I change button's IsEnabled property from DataTrigger on ListBox style? I try so many options, and all the same, I don't have a solution.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0.55 0.55" BorderBrush="black" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Нет студентов" Margin="20" FontSize="11"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Grid x:Name="gridButtons" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image Source="Resources/icons/add-icon.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedStudent}" Grid.Column="1">
                <Image Source="Resources/icons/delete-icon.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Grid.Column="2">
                <Image Source="Resources/icons/save-icon.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Grid.Column="3">
                <Image Source="Resources/icons/refresh-icon.png"></Image>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

I need when ListBox items count is 0, that btnSave's property IsEnabled is True.

I did all as mm8 wrote me and that still doesn't works.

What did i?

```html
<ListBox x:Name="lbStudents" Grid.Column="0" AlternationCount="2" BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="black" Margin="0 0 0 5" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="stpListBoxItem" Margin="4 7 4 7">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                                        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button x:Name="btnSave" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Image Source="Resources/icons/save-icon.png"></Image>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=lbStudents}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I spent very much time to this, but still don't found of the solution. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Create a `Trigger` for your `Button.Style` and then use `Binding.ElementName` Property like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129469/2946329

Comment: A Setter in a ListBox Style cannot set the property of a Button. Where is the ListBox in your XAML?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change button's IsEnabled property from DataTrigger on ListBox style?

You can't. A `Setter` in a `ListBox` `Style` can only set properties of the `ListBox` to which the `Style` is being applied.

You could apply a `Style` to the `Button` that binds to a property of the `ListBox` though:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSave" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Grid.Column="2">
    <Image Source="Resources/icons/save-icon.png"></Image>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=listBox}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

This only works if the `ListBox` with an `x:Name` of "listBox" is in the same naming scope as the `Button`.

What you really should do is to return `false` from the `CanExecute` method of your `SaveCommand` when the source collection that the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` is bound to has a count of `0`.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work and i don't understand why. I did all as you wrote me.

Comment: You forgot the `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />`. Just copy my sample style and replace "ElementName=listBox" by "ElementName=lbStudents".

Comment: And please don't post an answer that is not an answer to your question. Edit the question instead.

Comment: "What you really should do is to return false from the CanExecute method of your SaveCommand..."


This helped me figure out what my issue was... my CanExecute method was just returning true all the time, which was messing with my styling attempts