# TabItem Content IsEnabled binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a WPF application using MVVM pattern (at least I'm trying). There is `<TabControl>` with bound `ItemsSource`,which is an `ObservableCollection<TabModel> Tabs`. `Tabs` has `Name` and `Items` property, where Items is a list of `ControlModel`, which means Controls. I have problem with binding `IsEnabled` property to `Grid` where `Items` are placed.

Below there is a part of my code presenting the way I'm doing this:

```
private ObservableCollection<TabModel> tabs;

public ObservableCollection<TabModel> Tabs
{
    get
    {
        if (tabs == null)
        {
            tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabModel>();
            RefreshTabs();
        }
        return tabs;
    }
    set
    {
        tabs = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
    }
}
\\Tab Model
public string Name { get; set; }

private List<ControlModel> items;

public List<ControlModel> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

And xaml...

```
<TabControl Margin="0,100,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>        
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProductEditionEnabled}">
             <!--<Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">-->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ControlTemplateSelector}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

The part...
     `<Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProductEditionEnabled}">`

is not working. There is no error. This grid is always disabled. By default it's false.

```
private bool isProductEditionEnabled = false;

    public bool IsProductEditionEnabled
    {
        get { return isProductEditionEnabled; }
        set
        {
            isProductEditionEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsProductEditionEnabled");
        }
    }
```

The question is : How to bind `IsEnabled` in my case properly?

Comment: Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129379/set-visibility-of-button-depending-from-selected-tab/34129469#34129469

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks, but i forgot to mention that clicking a button is not only way that IsProductEditionEnabled is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inside a `DataTemplate` so you need to specify where the parent `DataContext` is when you do the binding, something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsProductEditionEnabled, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Almost perfect. DataContext.IsProductEditionEnabled was missing in binding path. Thank you.