# Select ComboBoxItem automatically based on different selected ComboBoxItem value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a form with some fields and two combo boxes. My view model contains some instances of `User` class, which contains `name` and `profile` attributes.

**ViewModel**

```
    public class UserViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<User> usersList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        private User selectedUser = new User();
        private User newUser = new User();

        public UserViewModel()
        {
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> UsersList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.usersList;
            }

            set
            {
                this.usersList = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return this.selectedUser;
            }

            set
            {
                this.selectedUser = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public User NewUser
        {
            get
            {
                return this.newUser;
            }

            set
            {
                this.newUser = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
 }
```

**Code-behind**

```
this.userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
this.DataContext = this.userViewModel;
```

**XAML**

```
<-- The DataContext for this ComboBox is the entire UserViewModel -->
<ComboBox
        Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
        SelectedItem="SelectedUser">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Mary" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="John"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

If I select an user from the first combobox, all form fields get filled with the existing data. Whatever user I select, it's going to be saved in `SelectedUser` through SelectedItem property.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="SelectedUser" Converter="{StaticResource NullToDependencyPropertyUnsetConverter}" />
            <Binding Path="NewUser" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    [...]
    <-- The DataContext for this ComboBox will be SelectedUser or NewUser, depending on the case -->
    <ComboBox
            Name="profileComboBox"
            Height="Auto"
            Width="Auto"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
            SelectedItem="Profile">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="User" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Admin"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    [...]
</Grid>
```

The ComboBox will have `SelectedUser` or `NewUser` as DataContext depending on whether `SelectedUser` is null or not. Then, whatever profile I select, it's going to be saved in `Profile` attribute of the previously selected user through SelectedItem property.

My problem is that the second combobox should select automatically the corresponding profile ("User" or "Admin") of the user just selected in the first combobox. Could this be achieved only using XAML?

Comment: This might helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129469/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari yeah, I tried that in the meanwhile, but no effect. I think it's something related to the DataContext, but not sure. Just in case you can come up with some idea, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `SelectedItem` of the second `ComboBox` to the `Profile` property of the currently selected `User`:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser.Profile}"
```

or

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.Profile, ElementName=userComboBox}"
```

Also remove the items from `ComboBox` and set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to the name of a property of the `Profile` type:

```
<ComboBox
        Name = "profileComboBox"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser.Profile}">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yeah, in the meanwhile I have been trying with that, but with no effect (also, I had to use `DisplayMemberPath` because `DisplayMemberName` property didn't exist). I think it's something related to DataContext, but not sure. I edited my question adding more code about this.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be `DisplayMemberPath`. Do you have a `SelectedUser` property that gets set?

Comment: Yes, in my view model, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The same with `NewUser`.

Comment: Do both `ComboBoxes` have the same `DataContext`? And what's the `ItemsSource` of the second `ComboBox`? It needs to be an `IEnumerable<Profile>` where all profiles are included.

Comment: In theory, they have different `DataContext`'s. About the `ItemsSource`: I thought that since I put the `ComboBoxItems`'s "manually" within the `ComboBox` syntax, `ItemsSource` wasn't needed. But maybe I wasn't right. I edited my question again with more details.

Comment: Of course you need an `ItemsSource`. And you should still remove the `ComboBoxItems`.

Comment: What if I set the ItemsSource to a `List<string> Profiles` of my ViewModel? I mean, it is not a `List<Profile> Profiles`. Should it change anything?

Comment: It should be an `List<Profile>` provided that `SelectedUser.Profile` is a `Profile`. You cannot mix types.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. `SelectedUser.Profile` is also a string.

Comment: Then the `ItemsSource` should be a `List<string>` and nothing else.